# Django: while updating record: ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key

Tags: python, django

There are similar issues on SO, but none alike this.

I would like to update a field in a record of a m2m model which has a unique constraint on `attendee` + `training`. This model is defined as (`model.py`):

```
class Occurrence(models.Model):
    attendee = models.ForeignKey(Attendee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    training = models.ForeignKey(Training, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    attended_date = models.DateField(default=date(1900, 12, 31))

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['attendee', 'training'], name='unique_attendee_training')
    ]
```

Now, consider e.g. that John has taken the Python course and already exists as record in the db. If I try get the date of when the training occurred, I would go like this:

```
from trainings.models import Attendee, Training, Occurrence
from datetime import date, datetime

attendee = Attendee.objects.get(pk='john@gmail.com')
training = Training.objects.get(pk='python310')
occurrence = Occurrence.objects.get(attendee=attendee, training=training)
print(occurrence.attended_date)
# datetime.date(2021, 11, 4)
```

However, if I try to update the date of this record, I get the error.

```
occurrence = Occurrence(attendee=attendee, training=training, attended_date=date(2021, 11, 5))
occurrence.save(update_fields=["attendee", "training", "attended_date"])
```

The error being:

```
ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key.
```

How do I update this record?

**Note**

I believe this should be enough to understand the question. But if you want to reproduce the whole issue, I post here the models (`model.py`) for Attendees and Trainings.

```
class Attendee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=30, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField('Last Name', max_length=30, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField("Email Address", max_length=75, blank=False, primary_key=True)
```

Using `email` as pk.

```
class Training(models.Model):
    long_name = models.CharField('Training Name', max_length=80, blank=False, null=False)
    short_name = models.CharField('Abbreviation', max_length=10, blank=False, null=False, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField('Descriprion', blank=True)
    alumni = models.ManyToManyField(Attendee, through='Occurrence')
```

Using `short_name` as pk. With `alumni` that relates `Attendee` and `Occurrence`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the record in the wrong way,

```
occurrence = Occurrence.objects.get(attendee=attendee, training=training)
print(occurrence.attended_date) # # datetime.date(2021, 11, 4)

# update the record like this
occurrence.attended_date = date(2021, 11, 5)
occurrence.save()
```

You can tell Django to update specific fields by passing the [`update_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#specifying-which-fields-to-save) parameter, as

```
# Use instead of `occurrence.save()`
occurrence.save(update_fields=["attended_date"])
```

Comment: This was so simple! I have been looking for hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `Model.objects.get()`, you can use `Model.objects.get_or_create()` method, in case you are not sure if the record for Occurrence exists or not.

For example, John has also taken the Excel course, but the entry for the `Occurrence` event is not in the db yet.

```
attendee = Attendee.objects.get(pk='john@gmail.com')
training = Training.objects.get(pk='Excel')
input_date = date(2021, 11, 5)

occurrence, created = Occurrence.objects.get_or_create(
    attendee=attendee, training=training, 
    defaults={'attended_date': input_date})
if not created: # created is True, because entry does not exists
    occurrence.attended_date = input_date

occurrence.save()
print(occurrence.attended_date)
# 2021-11-05
```

Where `occurrence` is the newly created instance and `created` is True. The insertion of the record is completed by `defaults={'attended_date': input_date}`. Otherwise, it would be false if the record already existed.

As I understand, this would cover both cases of `INSERT` and `UPDATE` of the record.